# Buttons in bulma-steps doesn't work Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, bulma

I have this HTML code in a child component:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma-steps@2.2.1/dist/css/bulma-steps.min.css">

<div class="steps" id="stepsDemo">
  <div class="step-item is-active is-success">
    <div class="step-marker">1</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Account</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-item">
    <div class="step-marker">2</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Profile</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-item">
    <div class="step-marker">3</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Social</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="step-item">
    <div class="step-marker">4</div>
    <div class="step-details">
      <p class="step-title">Finish</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-content">
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered is-active">
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Username</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus
                data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Confirm password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirm password"
                data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Firstname</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="firstname" id="firstname" type="text" placeholder="Firstname" autofocus
                data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Last name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last name" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control has-icon has-icon-right">
              <input class="input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Facebook account</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="facebook" id="facebook" type="text" placeholder="Facebook account url"
                autofocus data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field is-horizontal">
        <div class="field-label is-normal">
          <label class="label">Twitter account</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field-body">
          <div class="field">
            <div class="control">
              <input class="input" name="twitter" id="twitter" type="text" placeholder="Twitter account url" autofocus
                data-validate="require">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-content has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title is-4">Your account is now created!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="steps-actions">
    <div class="steps-action">
      <a data-nav="previous" class="button is-light">Previous</a>
    </div>
    <div class="steps-action">
      <a data-nav="next" class="button is-light">Next</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://wikiki.github.io/node_modules/bulma-extensions/bulma-steps/dist/js/bulma-steps.min.js"></script>
<script>bulmaSteps.attach();</script>
```

The issue here is that the "previous" and "next" buttons doesn't work, they take me to my default App route.
The weird thing is that copying this exact same code to a fiddle, it works as intended, as it can be visualized here: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/30159/
I have even tried to move this code to my `AppComponent.html` but with no luck.

Any clue on what it might be the problem here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you import css and js library correcly in your webpack ?

Comment: Hello!
What do you mean with webpack?

Comment: Angular project 2 and above, have a webpack process to compile and serve the server. if you install bulma extensions from npm, you should integrate them in your webpack config to be available to use it correctly